# Remove unwanted parts from strings in a column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for an efficient way to remove unwanted parts from strings in a DataFrame column.

Data looks like:

```
    time    result
1    09:00   +52A
2    10:00   +62B
3    11:00   +44a
4    12:00   +30b
5    13:00   -110a
```

I need to trim these data to:

```
    time    result
1    09:00   52
2    10:00   62
3    11:00   44
4    12:00   30
5    13:00   110
```

I tried `.str.lstrip('+-')` and .`str.rstrip('aAbBcC')`, but got an error:

```
TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 263, accepted):

```
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC'))
```

Comment: thx! that works. I'm still wrapping my mind around map(), not sure when to use or not use it...

Comment: I was pleased to see that this method also works with the replace function.

Comment: @eumiro how do you apply this result if iterating each column?

Comment: Can I use this function to replace a number such as the number 12?  If I do x.lstrip('12') it takes out all 1 and 2s.

Comment: Hi @eumiro, I want to remove punctuation (only dot .) only after the letter `c` and `p` from a string. How can I do that?

Comment: Now is warning because "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a Data Frame", I was trying to solve it, but I was not able, any workaround?

Comment: @JavierHuerta it works fine for me. Do you have like data['result'] = data['result'].map() with the equal sign?

Answer (score 255):

> ### How do I remove unwanted parts from strings in a column?

6 years after the original question was posted, pandas now has a good number of "vectorised" string functions that can succinctly perform these string manipulation operations.

This answer will explore some of these string functions, suggest faster alternatives, and go into a timings comparison at the end.

---

#### **[`.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)**

Specify the substring/pattern to match, and the substring to replace it with.

```
pd.__version__
# '0.24.1'

df    
    time result
1  09:00   +52A
2  10:00   +62B
3  11:00   +44a
4  12:00   +30b
5  13:00  -110a
```

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True)
df

    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     44
4  12:00     30
5  13:00    110
```

If you need the result converted to an integer, you can use [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html),

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True).astype(int)

df.dtypes
time      object
result     int64
dtype: object
```

If you don't want to modify `df` in-place, use [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df2 = df.assign(result=df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True))
df
# Unchanged
```

---

#### **[`.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)**

Useful for extracting the substring(s) you want to keep.

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df

    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     44
4  12:00     30
5  13:00    110
```

With `extract`, it is necessary to specify at least one capture group. `expand=False` will return a Series with the captured items from the first capture group.

---

###**[`.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)** and **[`.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get.html)**
Splitting works assuming all your strings follow this consistent structure.

```
# df['result'] = df['result'].str.split(r'\D').str[1]
df['result'] = df['result'].str.split(r'\D').str.get(1)
df

    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     44
4  12:00     30
5  13:00    110
```

Do not recommend if you are looking for a general solution.

---

> If you are satisfied with the succinct and readable `str`
> accessor-based solutions above, you can stop here. However, if you are
> interested in faster, more performant alternatives, keep reading.

---

### **Optimizing: List Comprehensions**

In some  circumstances, list comprehensions should be favoured over pandas string functions. The reason is because string functions are inherently hard to vectorize (in the true sense of the word), so most string and regex functions are only wrappers around loops with more overhead.

My write-up, [Are for-loops in pandas really bad? When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care), goes into greater detail.

The `str.replace` option can be re-written using `re.sub`

```
import re

# Pre-compile your regex pattern for more performance.
p = re.compile(r'\D')
df['result'] = [p.sub('', x) for x in df['result']]
df

    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     44
4  12:00     30
5  13:00    110
```

The `str.extract` example can be re-written using a list comprehension with `re.search`,

```
p = re.compile(r'\d+')
df['result'] = [p.search(x)[0] for x in df['result']]
df

    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     44
4  12:00     30
5  13:00    110
```

If NaNs or no-matches are a possibility, you will need to re-write the above to include some error checking. I do this using a function.

```
def try_extract(pattern, string):
    try:
        m = pattern.search(string)
        return m.group(0)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, AttributeError):
        return np.nan
 
p = re.compile(r'\d+')
df['result'] = [try_extract(p, x) for x in df['result']]
df

    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     44
4  12:00     30
5  13:00    110
```

We can also re-write @eumiro's and @MonkeyButter's answers using list comprehensions:

```
df['result'] = [x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC') for x in df['result']]
```

And,

```
df['result'] = [x[1:-1] for x in df['result']]
```

Same rules for handling NaNs, etc, apply.

---

### Performance Comparison

[image]

Graphs generated using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot). [Full code listing, for your reference.](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/c4a329fd00604e47d513b32e8a25f298) The relevant functions are listed below.

Some of these comparisons are unfair because they take advantage of the structure of OP's data, but take from it what you will. One thing to note is that every list comprehension function is either faster or comparable than its equivalent pandas variant.

**Functions**

> ```
> def eumiro(df):
>     return df.assign(
>         result=df['result'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC')))
>     
> def coder375(df):
>     return df.assign(
>         result=df['result'].replace(r'\D', r'', regex=True))
>
> def monkeybutter(df):
>     return df.assign(result=df['result'].map(lambda x: x[1:-1]))
>
> def wes(df):
>     return df.assign(result=df['result'].str.lstrip('+-').str.rstrip('aAbBcC'))
>
> def cs1(df):
>     return df.assign(result=df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', ''))
>
> def cs2_ted(df):
>     # `str.extract` based solution, similar to @Ted Petrou's. so timing together.
>     return df.assign(result=df['result'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False))
>
> def cs1_listcomp(df):
>     return df.assign(result=[p1.sub('', x) for x in df['result']])
>
> def cs2_listcomp(df):
>     return df.assign(result=[p2.search(x)[0] for x in df['result']])
>
> def cs_eumiro_listcomp(df):
>     return df.assign(
>         result=[x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC') for x in df['result']])
>
> def cs_mb_listcomp(df):
>     return df.assign(result=[x[1:-1] for x in df['result']])
> ```

Comment: any workaround to avoid the settingwithcopywarning: `Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: @PV8 not sure about your code, but check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986

Comment: For anyone that's new to REGEX like me, \D is the same as [^\d] (anything that's not a digit) [from here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). So we're basically replacing all the non-digits in the string with nothing.

Comment: Such a complete answer should deserve to be THE answer.

Comment: If you are using a newer version of pandas and using regex, you should pass in the argument `regex=True`, otherwise your regular expression might not work correctly. For example, `df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', '')` would be `df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True)`. (See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html for more information).

Comment: @AlexandreGaubil thanks! updated, feel free to suggest any other edits as necessary and i can take a look.

Answer (score 63):

i'd use the pandas replace function, very simple and powerful as you can use regex. Below i'm using the regex \D to remove any non-digit characters but obviously you could get quite creative with regex.

```
data['result'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't work. I'm wondering if it only works when you want to replace an entire string instead of just replacing a substring part.

Comment: @bgenchel - I used this method to replace part of a string in a pd.Series: `df.loc[:, 'column_a'].replace(regex=True, to_replace="my_prefix", value="new_prefix")`. This will convert a string like "my_prefixaaa" to "new_prefixaaa".

Comment: what does the r do in to_replace=r'\D'?

Comment: @LucaGuarro from the python docs: "The r prefix, making the literal a raw string literal, is needed in this example because escape sequences in a normal “cooked” string literal that are not recognized by Python, as opposed to regular expressions, now result in a DeprecationWarning and will eventually become a SyntaxError."

Answer (score 42):

In the particular case where you know the number of positions that you want to remove from the dataframe column, you can use string indexing inside a lambda function to get rid of that parts:

Last character:

```
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
```

First two characters:

```
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: str(x)[2:])
```

Comment: I need to trim the geo coordinates to 8 characters (including (.), (-)) and in case if they are less than 8 I need to insert '0' at last to make all the coordinates 8 characters. What is simpler way to do so ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem but you might need to change the lambda function to something like "{0:.8f}".format(x)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. In simple words I have dataframe with geo coordinates -- latitude & longitude as two columns. The characters length is more than 8 characters and I was keep only 8 characters starting from first which should include (-) and (.) also.

Answer (score 18):

There's a bug here: currently cannot pass arguments to `str.lstrip` and `str.rstrip`:

http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2411

EDIT: 2012-12-07 this works now on the dev branch:

```
In [8]: df['result'].str.lstrip('+-').str.rstrip('aAbBcC')
Out[8]: 
1     52
2     62
3     44
4     30
5    110
Name: result
```

Answer (score 11):

A very simple method would be to use the `extract` method to select all the digits. Simply supply it the regular expression `'\d+'` which extracts any number of digits.

```
df['result'] = df.result.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int)
df

    time  result
1  09:00      52
2  10:00      62
3  11:00      44
4  12:00      30
5  13:00     110
```

Answer (score 7):

Suppose your DF is having those extra character in between numbers as well.The last entry.

```
  result   time
0   +52A  09:00
1   +62B  10:00
2   +44a  11:00
3   +30b  12:00
4  -110a  13:00
5   3+b0  14:00
```

You can try str.replace to remove characters not only from start and end but also from in between.

```
DF['result'] = DF['result'].str.replace('\+|a|b|\-|A|B', '')
```

Output:

```
  result   time
0     52  09:00
1     62  10:00
2     44  11:00
3     30  12:00
4    110  13:00
5     30  14:00
```

Answer (score 6):

I often use list comprehensions for these types of tasks because they're often faster.

There can be big differences in performance between the various methods for doing things like this (i.e. modifying every element of a series within a DataFrame). Often a list comprehension can be fastest - see code race below for this task:

```
import pandas as pd
#Map
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00'], 'result':['+52A','+62B','+44a','+30b','-110a']})
%timeit data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC'))
10000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop
#List comprehension
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00'], 'result':['+52A','+62B','+44a','+30b','-110a']})
%timeit data['result'] = [x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('aAbBcC') for x in data['result']]
10000 loops, best of 3: 117 µs per loop
#.str
data = pd.DataFrame({'time':['09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00'], 'result':['+52A','+62B','+44a','+30b','-110a']})
%timeit data['result'] = data['result'].str.lstrip('+-').str.rstrip('aAbBcC')
1000 loops, best of 3: 336 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using regular expression:

```
import re
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[-+A-Za-z]',x)
```

Answer (score 0):

using "str.replace" is more fast than lambda and map when your data dimention is large:

```
your_data["result"]=your_data["result"].str.replace("+","")
your_data["result"]=your_data["result"].str.replace("-","")
```