# Replacing part of string in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a similar problem to the one posted here:

[Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

I need to remove newline characters from within a string in a DataFrame. Basically, I've accessed an api using python's json module and that's all ok. Creating the DataFrame works amazingly, too. However, when I want to finally output the end result into a csv, I get a bit stuck, because there are newlines that are creating false 'new rows' in the csv file.

So basically I'm trying to turn this:

'...this is a paragraph.

And this is another paragraph...'

into this:

'...this is a paragraph. And this is another paragraph...'

I don't care about preserving any kind of '\n' or any special symbols for the paragraph break. So it can be stripped right out.

I've tried a few variations:

```
misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].strip('\n')

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

here's another

```
misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].str.strip('\n')

TypeError: wrapper() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].map(lambda x: x.strip('\n'))
misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].map(lambda x: x.strip('\n\t'))
```

There is no error message, but the newline characters don't go away, either. Same thing with this:

```
misc = misc.replace('\n', '')
```

The write to csv line is this:

```
misc_id.to_csv('C:\Users\jlalonde\Desktop\misc_w_id.csv', sep=' ', na_rep='', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Version of Pandas is 0.9.1

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`strip` only removes the specified characters at the beginning and end of the string.  If you want to remove *all* `\n`, you need to use `replace`.

```
misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].str.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: is this `inplace`?

Comment: @user1767754: It modifies the original DataFrame, if that's what you mean.  It's not strictly "in place" though; it creates a new column with the modified values and then assigns it back, overwriting the original column.

Comment: **.str** is important, missed it at first glance.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `regex` parameter of `replace` method to achieve that:

```
misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].replace(to_replace='\n', value='', regex=True)
```

Comment: If `product_desc` may contain mixed values (e.g. float, str...) then convert it to `np.str` to work properly: `misc['product_desc'] = misc['product_desc'].astype(np.str).replace(to_replace='\n', value='', regex=True)`. Otherwise only `str` values will be replaced...

Comment: to_replace can use a list, too: `.replace(to_replace=['\n', '\t'], value='', regex=True)`

Comment: How do you replace items that are within a word?  Example:  'This is a sente\tnce'.  (Remove \t)

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland code from the answer should work for that cases.