# Removing Partial Strings from Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas

Similar question to : [Replacing part of string in python pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345739/replacing-part-of-string-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

However it wont work!?

Panas 23.4

Given the following df column:

```
    Expression
    XYZ&(ABC|DEF)
   (HIJ&FTL&JKK)&(ABC|DEF)
   (FML|AXY|AND)&(ABC|DEF)
```

I want to strip a substring that may be in each column.

```
flag = '(ABC|DEF)'
andFlag = '&' + flag #the reasoning for doing this is that 'flag' may change


#Below are all different ways I have tried to achieve this, none have worked. 
df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].replace(andFlag, '', regex=True)
df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(andFlag, '', x))
df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].replace(to_replace=andFlag, value= '', regex=True)
df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].str.replace(andFlag, '')
df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].str.replace(andFlag, '', regex=True)
```

I have tried all of these functions with and without `regex=True` to no avail.

Expected output:

```
    Expression
    XYZ
   (HIJ&FTL&JKK)
   (FML|AXY|AND)
```

I'm going slightly crazy trying to figure this out, it seems so simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Parenthesis and the vertical bar are special character in regex, so if you want to match these character, you can add a backslash '\' before such as:

```
flag = '\(ABC\|DEF\)' #see this is changed
andFlag = '&' + flag
print (df['Expression'].replace(andFlag, '', regex=True))

0              XYZ
1    (HIJ&FTL&JKK)
2    (FML|AXY|AND)
Name: Expression, dtype: object
```

Comment: Regardless of that, shouldn't it have worked when they tried `df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].str.replace(andFlag, '')`?

Comment: @ZacharyOldham no, but you are right, by setting the paramater regex to False (by default it is True) then you get the right answer `df['Expression'].str.replace(andFlag, '', regex=False)`

Comment: Ah, so is `regex=True` the default?

Comment: @ZacharyOldham apparently :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.replace` and more important, set `regex=False` for literal matching:

```
df['Expression'] = df['Expression'].str.replace(andFlag, '', regex=False)

      Expression
0            XYZ
1  (HIJ&FTL&JKK)
2  (FML|AXY|AND)
```