# Data munging in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-munging

I have a CSV file with lines look like:

```
ID,98.4,100M,55M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#,
```

I can read it in with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Given a particular column, I would like to split the rows by ID and then output the mean and standard deviation for each ID.

My first problem is, how can I remove all the non-numeric parts from the numbers such as "100M" and "0N#" which should be 100 and 0 respectively.

I also tried looping over the relevant headers and using

```
df[header].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
```

as suggested in [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column) .

However this changes 98.4 into 984.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

Comment: @Evert Added an edit to show how I need to cope with decimal points too.

Comment: The duplicate I listed suggest to use `rstrip`, with the characters you'd like to remove. So ...`rstrip('MN#')` should work nicely for your input, using the lambda suggested in the duplicate (of course, you can leave out the `lstrip` part).

Comment: @Evert The problem is that MN# are not the only non-numeric characters.   I suppose I would have to do lstrip to as well?

Comment: @Evert Also my looping over the headers is not working. `for header in list(df)[9:-3]:` gives me the columns not the headers. What is the right way to do that?

Comment: @eleanora Can you give a full list of non-numeric characters you'd expect or do you just want to strip any characters that aren't numeric? In either case, you can still use `rstrip`, you just need to pass a string with all the characters to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract):

```
In [356]:
import io
import pandas as pd
t="""ID,98.4,100M,55M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)
df

Out[356]:
   0     1     2    3    4    5     6    7    8     9    10    11    12   13  \
0  ID  98.4  100M  55M  65M  75M  100M  75M  65M  100M  98M  100M  100M  92M   

   14   15  
0  0#  0N#  

In [357]:
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
df

Out[357]:
   0     1    2   3   4   5    6   7   8    9   10   11   12  13  14  15
0  ID  98.4  100  55  65  75  100  75  65  100  98  100  100  92   0   0
```

If you have float numbers then you can use the following regex:

```
In [379]:
t="""ID,98.4,100.50M,55.234M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)
df

Out[379]:
   0     1        2        3    4    5     6    7    8     9    10    11  \
0  ID  98.4  100.50M  55.234M  65M  75M  100M  75M  65M  100M  98M  100M   

     12   13  14   15  
0  100M  92M  0#  0N#  

In [380]:    
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d+)').astype(np.float)
df

Out[380]:
   0     1      2       3   4   5    6   7   8    9   10   11   12  13  14  15
0  ID  98.4  100.5  55.234  65  75  100  75  65  100  98  100  100  92 NaN NaN
```

so `(\d+\.?\d+)` looks for groups containing `\d+` 1 or more digits with `\.?` optional decimal point and `\d+` 1 or more further digits after the decimal point

**EDIT**

OK edited my regex pattern:

```
In [408]:
t="""Name,97.7,0A,0A,65M,0A,100M,5M,75M,100M,90M,90M,99M,90M,0#,0N#"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)
df

Out[408]:
     0     1   2   3    4   5     6   7    8     9    10   11   12   13  14  \
0  Name  97.7  0A  0A  65M  0A  100M  5M  75M  100M  90M  90M  99M  90M  0#   

    15  
0  0N#  

In [409]:    
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract(r'(\d+\.*\d*)').astype(np.float)
df

Out[409]:
     0     1   2   3   4   5    6   7   8    9   10  11  12  13  14  15
0  Name  97.7   0   0  65   0  100   5  75  100  90  90  99  90   0   0
```

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None)

TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: Ignore the `io.StringIO` bit this is just me reading in your text as a file object in your case `df=pd.read_csv(filename)` is fine

Comment: If this is the whole file "Name",97.7,0A,0A,65M,0A,100M,5M,75M,100M,90M,90M,99M,90M,0#,0N#," Your code gives me "0  Name NaN NaN NaN  65 NaN  100 NaN  75  100  90  90  99  90 NaN NaN NaN"

Comment: The edited version is better and gives `0  Name NaN   0   0  65   0  100   5  75  100  90  90  99  90   0   0 NaN`. This still kills the 97.7 at the start.

Comment: I don't see that, can you post raw input data and code into your question

Comment: It's unnecessary to parse the `97.7` in this case as pandas will set the `dtype` to `float64` which is why I indexed from `2:` onwards

Comment: True but I would like to be able to handle 97.7M too .

Comment: if it was `97.7M` then my code will work, the problem is that calling `.str.extract` will raise an error as this only works for `str` columns and not numeric ones

Answer (score 2):

> My first problem is, how can I remove all the non-numeric parts from the numbers such as "100M" and "0N#" which should be 100 and 0 respectively.

```
import re
df = pd.read_csv(yourfile, header=None)
df.columns = ['ID'] + list(df.columns)[1:]
df = df.stack().apply(lambda v: re.sub('[^0-9]','', v) 
                 if isinstance(v, str) else v).astype(float).unstack()
df.groupby('ID').agg(['std', 'mean'])
```

Here `.stack()` transforms the dataframe into a Series, `.apply()` calls the lambda for each value, `re.sub()` removes any non-numeric characters, `.astype()` converts to numeric and `unstack()` transforms the Series back into a dataframe. This works equally well for both integers and floating point numbers.

> Given a particular column, I would like to split the rows by ID and then output the mean and standard deviation for each ID.

```
 # for all columns
 df.groupby('ID').agg(['std', 'mean'])
 # for specific column
 df.groupby('ID')['<colname>'].agg(['std', 'mean'])
```

[image: output dataframe]

Here's the data used in the example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
s="""
1,98.4,100M,55M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#,
1,98.4,100M,55M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#,
2,98.4,100M,55M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#,
2,98.4,100M,55M,65M,75M,100M,75M,65M,100M,98M,100M,100M,92M,0#,0N#,
"""
yourfile = StringIO(s)
```