# Remove unwanted parts from strings in a range of columns

Tags: python, pandas

*Part 1*

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)  but i have a range of colums named A - J all of which have hyphens in place of NaN on Series with numeric values (see example below). How do I replace all of them rather than go through each column at a time as demonstrated in that answer.

```
Sample column A
1000
2000
3000
-
1000
```

*Part 2*

Is there a way to use regex to remove all '-', ',' , '.' from a dataframe?

Comment: Showing a sample of your data will help with understanding what you want

Comment: try this: `df.replace(r'[\s\-,\.]+', '', regex=True, inplace=True)` or just use [pd.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Part #1***

You can define '-' to be a NaN value when reading in the data to your DataFrame. More specifically by use of `na_values` in your `pd.read_csv()` call.

See docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

***Part #2***

As earlier suggested by MaxU you can use `.replace()` like this:

```
df.replace(r'[\s\-,\.]+', r'', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

> Note that this will not have any effect on non-strings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If that helped you can accept the answer or vote it up or both. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the columns.

Selected columns:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a-b', 'c-d'], 'b': ['x-y', 'z-z'], 'c': ['x-y', 'z-z']})
>>> df
     a    b    c
0  a-b  x-y  x-y
1  c-d  z-z  z-z
>>> for col_name in 'ab':
        df[col_name] = df[col_name].str.replace('-', '0')
>>> df
     a    b    c
0  a0b  x0y  x-y
1  c0d  z0z  z-z
```

All columns:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a-b', 'c-d'], 'b': ['x-y', 'z-z'], 'c': ['x-y', 'z-z']})

>>> for col_name in df.columns:
        df[col_name] = df[col_name].str.replace('-', '0')
>>> df
     a    b    c
0  a0b  x0y  x0y
1  c0d  z0z  z0z
```