# Removing characters from a string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar question to this one: [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column).

So I used:

```
temp_dataframe['PPI'] = temp_dataframe['PPI'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('PPI/'))
```

Most, of the items start with a 'PPI/' but not all. It seems that when an item without the 'PPI/' suffix encountered this error:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are those caused by missing values, or actual floats? Can you show value of a row that causes this? (Trying to learn and understand here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
temp_dataframe['PPI'].replace('PPI/','',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

or [string.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.replace('PPI/','')
```

Answer (score 3):

use vectorised `str.lstrip`:

```
temp_dataframe['PPI'] = temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.lstrip('PPI/')
```

it looks like you may have missing values so you should mask those out or replace them:

```
temp_dataframe['PPI'].fillna('', inplace=True)
```

or

```
temp_dataframe.loc[temp_dataframe['PPI'].notnull(), 'PPI'] = temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.lstrip('PPI/')
```

maybe a better method is to filter using `str.startswith` and use `split` and access the string after the prefix you want to remove:

```
temp_dataframe.loc[temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.startswith('PPI/'), 'PPI'] = temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.split('PPI/').str[1]
```

As @JonClements pointed out that `lstrip` is removing whitespace rather than removing the prefix which is what you're after.

**update**

Another method is to pass a regex pattern that looks for the optionally prefix and extract all characters after the prefix:

```
temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.extract('(?:PPI/)?(.*)', expand=False)
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.lstrip` probably isn't what the OP wants - it'll remove all characters that are `P`, `I` or `/` from the beginning of the string - it's not actually removing a prefix if it exists...

Comment: Or possibly `temp_dataframe['PPI'].str.extract('(?:PPI/)?(.*)', expand=False)`