# Pandas DataFrame: Remove everything after a non-digit character

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a question that is similar to this one: [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

The difference is that I want to remove all characters after a non digit character appear, for example:

```
    time    result
1   09:00   52m2 +6
2   10:00   62m2+balkon
3   11:00   57.+2 balkona
4   12:00   30 m2
5   13:00   46(43)
```

I need to trim this data to:

```
    time    result
1   09:00   52
2   10:00   62
3   11:00   57
4   12:00   30
5   13:00   46
```

I tried solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919479/removing-characters-from-a-string-in-pandas) and many more similar questions, but I couldn't find this specific use case.

Comment: Try `data['result'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'^(\d+).+',value=r'\1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df.result = df.result.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
print (df)
    time result
1  09:00     52
2  10:00     62
3  11:00     57
4  12:00     30
5  13:00     46
```