# How to remove alphabet from float values in dataframe column

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe :

```
A            B
10.1        33.3
11.2        44.2s
12.3        11.3s
14.2s       *
15.4s       nan
```

i want output as

```
A            B
10.1        33.3
11.2        44.2
12.3        11.3
14.2          0
15.4         0
```

How do I remove these tailing alphabets

I have tried this code

1st approach:

```
bulb_temp_df['A'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(float)
bulb_temp_df['B'].str.extract('(\d)').astype(float)
```

2nd approach:

```
bulb_temp_df['A'] = 
bulb_temp_df['A'].astype(str)
bulb_temp_df['A'] = 
bulb_temp_df['A'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('aAbBcC'))
```

These are not working. They are not removing the tailing s from the columns.

third approach

```
bulb_temp_df[cols]=bulb_temp_df[cols].apply(lambda x:x.str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)',expand=False)
                                .astype(float)
                                .fillna(0))`
```

All these are not working. The last one removes the tailing s but it converts the values without 's' to zero or nan.

Comment: Try to strip data after used `rstrip`. Example `x.rstrip('aAbBcC').strip()`

Comment: Thought this was an r question so if you know how to use that you can just do this `x2<-gsub("[^0-9.]", "", as.character(unlist(x)));x2[x2==""]<-0;x3<-matrix(as.numeric(x2),5,2);colnames(x3)<-c("A","B");x3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I´m going to create a reproducible example:

```
from io import StringIO
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = StringIO('''\
       A           B
1   10.1        33.3
2   11.2       44.2s
3   12.3       11.3s
4   14.2s          *
5   15.4s        nan
''')


df = pd.read_table(s, sep='\s\s+',engine='python')
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str)
```

Now, you can use regex and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9^\-\.]+', '', x)).replace('', np.float64(0)).astype('float64') 

print(df)
```

**Output:**

> ```
>       A     B
> 1  10.1  33.3
> 2  11.2  44.2
> 3  12.3  11.3
> 4  14.2   0.0
> 5  15.4   0.0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This isn`t super clean, but it works!

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def cleanup(df, column):
    temp = str(df[column])
    vals = re.split("(\d+\.\d+|\*|NaN)", temp)[1::2]
    out = [float(a.replace('*', '0').replace('NaN', '0')) for a in vals]

    return out

bulb_temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(cleanup(bulb_temp_df, 'A'), cleanup(bulb_temp_df, 'B'))), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

What this does is it makes a new pandas dataframe with the formatted data. It formats it by searching for the regex `(\d+\.\d+|\*|NaN)` which will find all floats, *'s or NaN's. Using this regex, we split the column which is turned into a string based on finding one of the 3 mentioned patterns. Then we take every odd index, since that holds what were interested in.

Now, we have a list of strings on the floats without s, and the * and Nans. the list comprehension replaces all the *'s and NaN's with 0 and casts all the elements to float (since they are still strings).

Not elegant, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a simple approach (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49536987/3502341))-
Use `replace` to retain only the digits (and `dot` and `minus` sign).
This would remove characters, alphabets or anything that is not defined in `to_replace` attribute.

So, the solution is:
`df['A1'].replace(regex=True, inplace=True, to_replace=r'[^0-9.\-]', value=r'']`
`df['A1'] = df['A1'].astype(float64)`