# Error: Unable to parse string "*" at position 6116 - Convert Object Type to Int - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

This question has been asked in many threads and has worked for others, but not for me. I am trying to convert `object` data type into `int` to perform a group by aggregation. 
Following are what I tried and the errors I got so far, (I am using python 3)
According to this link, I tried [these two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39173813/pandas-convert-dtype-object-to-int?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
df['my_var'] = df['my_var'].astype(str).astype(int)
df['my_var'] = df['my_var'].astype(int)
```

Same error for both:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '*'

And then I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677933/converting-object-to-int-pandas),

```
df['my_var'] = pd.to_numeric(df['my_var'])
```

I got an error:

> ValueError: Unable to parse string "*" at position 6116

This is how `dtypes` looks like,

```
print (df.dtypes)
my_var object
dtype: object
```

I know some of the similar questions are down voted, however, I did not succeed using those answers. Is it a version error? I am finding it difficult to understand this error. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Somewhere in your dataframe (actually, at the position 6116) you have a string `"*"` that you attempt to convert to an integer number. Don't do that.

Comment: @DYZ I checked for special characters using `df.applymap(np.isreal)` and it was all `flase` is that the correct way to check?

Comment: But you try to convert to integers, not reals. They are not the same.

Comment: @DYZ yeah I am going to check them again, any idea why `df['my_var'] = df['my_var'].astype(str).astype(int)` doesn't convert to `int`?

Comment: Exactly because `"*"` is _not_ an int.

Comment: @DYZ Yup, got it, what is that 'position 6116'? is it the row number? I checked with `df.ix[6116]` and I did not see any special characters in the output.

Comment: Not sure. Check `df[df['my_var']=='*']`.

Comment: `df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['my_var'], errors='coerce').isnull()]` - should show you all rows where `my_var` couldn't been converted to numeric value...

Comment: Your question can be easily answered as soon as you decide what would you like to do with those values that can't be converted to integer values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting suggestions from #DYZ and #MaxU, it was an error due to the special character `*` in a row in in my DataFrame. (Error message was obvious)

As suggested, using,

```
df[df['my_var']=='*']
```

and

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['my_var'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
```

I found where exactly the special character was. Then used regular expression method to strip off special characters using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277928/remove-special-characters-in-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 1):

I used 0 to replace anything that isn't a number but you can use any other value that makes sense to you e.g. -999999 (not a suggested practice obviously but just an example)

```
pd.to_numeric(df.my_var, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```