# How to extract first two characters from string using regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

reference:  [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

In reference to an answer provided in the link above.  I've researched some regular expressions and I plan to dive deeper but in the meantime I could use some help.

My dataframe is something like:

df:

```
  c_contofficeID
0           0109
1           0109
2           3434
3         123434  
4         1255N9
5           0109
6         123434
7           55N9
8           5599
9           0109
```

Psuedo Code

If the first two characters are a 12 remove them. Or alternatively, add a 12 to the characters that don't have a 12 in the first two characters.

Result would look like:

```
  c_contofficeID
0           0109
1           0109
2           3434
3           3434  
4           55N9
5           0109
6           3434
7           55N9
8           5599
9           0109
```

I'm using the answer from the link above as a starting point:

```
df['contofficeID'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'\D',value=r'')
```

I've tried the following:

Attempt 1)

```
df['contofficeID'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'[1][2]',value=r'')
```

Attempt 2)

```
df['contofficeID'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'$[1][2]',value=r'')
```

Attempt 3)

```
df['contofficeID'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'?[1]?[2]',value=r'')
```

Comment: `^12` is the regex for "starts with '12'"

Comment: What if you have "1234"?  Should "12" be retained in that case or discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***new answers***
per comment from @Addison

```
# '12(?=.{4}$)' makes sure we have a 12 followed by exactly 4 something elses
df.c_contofficeID.str.replace('^12(?=.{4}$)', '')
```

If ID's must have four characters, it's simpler to

```
df.c_contofficeID.str[-4:]
```

***old answer***
use `str.replace`

```
df.c_contofficeID.str.replace('^12', '').to_frame()
```

[image]

Comment: This is dangerous, as it won't work for `1234`. Please use something like `^12(?=.{4}$)`