# Removing part of a value in a certain column in a dataframe , and returning a DF

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, multi-index

I have the following Data Frame named:  mydf:

```
        A                  B
0       3de (1ABS)      Adiran
1       3SA (SDAS)      Adel
2       7A (ASA)        Ronni
3       820 (SAAa)      Emili
```

I want to remove the " (xxxx)" and keeps the values in column A , so the dataframe (mydf) will look like:

```
        A          B
0       3de      Adiran
1       3SA      Adel
2       7A       Ronni
3       820      Emili
```

I have tried :

```
print mydf['A'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r" \(.+\)", "", x) )
```

but then I get a Series object back and not a dataframe object.

I have also tried to use replace:

`df.replace([' \(.*\)'],[""], regex=True)`, But it didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [str.split()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) method:

```
In [3]: df.A = df.A.str.split('\s+\(').str[0]

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
     A                   B
0  3de              Adiran
1  3SA                Adel
2   7A               Ronni
3  820               Emili
```

or using [str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method:

```
In [9]: df.A = df.A.str.extract(r'([^\(\s]*)', expand=False)

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
     A                   B
0  3de              Adiran
1  3SA                Adel
2   7A               Ronni
3  820               Emili
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.
What is the difference between using df['A'] and using df.A ? From my understanding df['A'] returns a series object, but df.A just modifies column A in the df.