# Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings before and after what I want to keep

Tags: python, pandas

In my data_cleaner dataset I have the column (feature) 'Project ID'. This identifies the project and it has a format 'code/YEAR/code'. I'm only interested in the project's year so I want to get rid of everything before the first / and everything after the second /.

```
Project ID  
AGPG/2013/1 
AGPG/2013/10
AGPG/2013/12
AGPG/2013/18
AGPG/2013/19
```

The closest I got was to strip what's before with

```
data_cleaner['Project ID'] = data_cleaner['Project ID'].str.strip("AGPG")
```

(but down the line there are other letters so this is not escalable)

And then I did

```
data_cleaner['Project ID'] = data_cleaner['Project ID'].str.strip('/')
```

This got rid of the first bit, I can't manage to get rid of what's after the year.

```
Project ID  
2013/1  
2013/10
2013/12
2013/18
2013/19
```

I read this post but didn't help me [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and select second `lists`:

```
data_cleaner['Project ID'] = data_cleaner['Project ID'].str.split('/').str[1]
```

Or [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) by regex - `/(\d{4})/` means get numeric with length `4` between `//`:

```
data_cleaner['Project ID'] = data_cleaner['Project ID'].str.extract('/(\d{4})/', expand=False)

print (data_cleaner)
  Project ID
0       2013
1       2013
2       2013
3       2013
4       2013
```