# Filter dates according to the month and paste them in a new column with month as column name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, mapping

I have about 30+ columns with dates all ranging in current year for databases. I need to filter dates and arrange them in new columns, as in all dates falling in May in a new column called May while all dates in June in another column June. 
(I have a schedule for databases which all the release date in the current year in different columns. I need to create a column month-wise and add dates in these columns)

I did write a code but I could only filter dates of one of the many columns and also the date format is distorted

```
sf.loc[(sf['Unnamed: 16']>= start) & (sf['Unnamed: 16']<=end), 'CurrentMonth'] = sf['Unnamed: 16']
```

[Input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu3rb.png)
[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yLOr.png)

Comment: You should provide a sample of your dataset so people can check whether a piece of code works or not. Provide a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Please refer attached images - Input file & Output file

Comment: @nahusznaj - thanks for sharing the link. well we could only filter the data frame using the methods mentioned. well i am looking for a code to copy the result and paste it in a column without filtering the data-frame.  Did you check the attached images?

Answer (score 0):

If the first bit managed to filter what you wanted with:
`sf.loc[(sf['Unnamed: 16']>= start) & (sf['Unnamed: 16']<=end), 'CurrentMonth'] = sf['Unnamed: 16']`

Then create a column like this

`sf['New column'] = values for new column`

I can't reproduce the problem as you haven't provided a useful dataset (images are not useful for this - see the instructions for how to create a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have edited the post if it might explain a bit better - really sorry that i cannot explain it well. The code that i use could filter the dates of particular month only in one column and paste it in new column however the output is not in date format. I want to write a code to filter all columns and save the dates from all these columns in one single column

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I can tell that you have several questions in your post. Separate your problem in smaller questions: how to select some values out a column (that's the link I put above with lots of methods), how to create a new column for a dataframe, how to strip off parts of a column that you don't need. And attack each question separately.

Comment: See [split](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754202/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-before-and-after-what-i-wan) by @jezrael

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try to work on some code

Comment: That’s unfortunate. Did you get a solution to your problem?