# Python: Replacing alphanumeric values in Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, character

I have words with \t and \r at the beginning of the words that I am trying to strip out without stripping the actual words.

For example `"\tWant to go to the mall.\rTo eat something."`

I have tried a few things from SO over three days. Its a Pandas Dataframe so I thought this answer pertained the best:

[Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

But formulating from that for my own solution is not working.

```
i = df['Column'].replace(regex=False,inplace=False,to_replace='\t',value='')
```

I did not want to use regex since the expression has been difficult to make being that I am attempting to strip out '\t' and if possible also '\r'.

Here is my regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/92CUV5/5

Comment: Maybe a regex is not so bad after all: `df['Column'].replace(regex=True,inplace=False,to_replace='\\t|\\r',value='')`

Comment: Try just `str.replace`: `df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace(r'\\[tr]','')`. However, it might still affect some strings like URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
def remove_chars(text):
    return str(re.sub(r'[\t\r]','',text))

i = df['Column'].map(remove_chars)
```