# How to remove different strings from several columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pd dataframe which looks like this:

```
    keyword     |    ranks    |search_type | search_volume
0   keyword1    |[{'rank': 1}]| 1          | {'search_volume': 10}
1   keyword1    |[{'rank': 1}]| 2          |{'search_volume': 10}
2   keyword2    |[{'rank': 1}]| 1          |{'search_volume': 390}
3   keyword2    |[{'rank': 1}]| 2          |{'search_volume': 390}
4   keyword3    |[{'rank': 1}]| 1          |{'search_volume': 170}
...
```

Columns `ranks` and `search_volume` should be integers containing numbers only, and I'm trying to find a way to remove `[{'rank':` , `{'search_volume':` and and closing brackets, so the table looks like:

```
    keyword     | ranks |search_type | search_volume
0   keyword1    |   1   |   1        |10
1   keyword1    |   1   |   2        |10
2   keyword2    |   1   |   1        |390
3   keyword2    |   1   |   2        |390
4   keyword3    |   1   |   1        |170
...
```

I've tried this: `df['ranks'].replace('[{\'rank\':','',inplace=True)` however it didn't do anything. also this is not the quickest way of solving this problem.

I've had a look at this thread [Pandas DataFrame: remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/pandas-dataframe-remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column), this solution is for one column at a time (it would be good to strip out out all unwated strings at once) and it returns this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'`.

I'm using python 3.

Comment: Try: `df['ranks'].apply(lambda x: x[0]["rank"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way using [`pd.Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['ranks'] = df['ranks'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['rank'])
df['search_volume'] = df['search_volume'].apply(lambda x: x['search_volume'])
```

This assumes your `ranks` series contains lists, and your `search_volume` series contains dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

Use apply:

```
df['ranks'] = df['ranks'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['rank'])
df['search_volume'] = df['search_volume'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['search_volume'])
```

**BONUS**

This one will work in your case, to make it a one-liner:

```
df[['ranks', 'search_volume']] = df[['ranks', 'search_volume']].applymap(lambda x: x[0].values()[0])
```