# pandas type error when trying to modify values of a column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have csv file that looks something like this

```
     x     y  z 
0  a_b_c  30 40
1  d_e_f  50 57
```

I am trying to modify column x by splitting the string at the first underscore and only keeping the string right before it. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13682381/6943310) I came up with the following solution:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].map(lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[0])
```

However, i get an error message

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
df['x'].str.split("_").str[0]
```

when you call `df['x'].map(...)`, you operate each `element` of `x` column. you can't use `str` on an `element`. It can be used on the `x` column, a `Series`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The error message still persists. Do i have to explicitly tell pandas its a string or something?