# Python Remove specific string in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a one specific column like this:

```
var
100 asc
200 asc
150 asc
75  asc
```

I want to remove asc and retain as number so to get

```
var
100
200
150
75
```

Running

number =df['var'].replace('\asc',regex=True)

Yet nothing happens resulting df is exactly the same as the original one, yet no error are shown...

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column)

Comment: `df['var'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['var'] = df['var'].str.strip(' asc')
```