# How would I remove multiple values within one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file named df that looks like this:

```py
Size       ID      File
500 TB     A       200 TB 
200 TB     B       100 TB
600 TB     C       300 TB
```

The numerical value along with the text, which is always `'TB'`, are within one column. How would I transform this and remove the 'TB' text from both columns to give me the desired output of:

```
Size       ID      File
500        A       200 
200        B       100 
600        C       300
```

This is what I am doing:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df[df[","] > ,]
```

I am still researching this. Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: That's addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Apply [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to the columns with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), and then select the first element from the list created by `.split`, with `.str[0]`.
- This will work, as long as the pattern shown in the sample is consistent, with the undesired text after the space.
- Using `.apply` in this way, will apply the `lambda` function to all the columns.

  - If `ID` has values with spaces, then this solution will cause an issue there, which can be resolved by using apply only on the columns that need to be fixed.

    - `df[['Size', 'File']] = df[['Size', 'File']].apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').str[0])`
  - If there was only one column to fix, then `.apply` isn't required.

    - `df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.split(' ').str[0]`

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Size': ['500 TB', '200 TB', '600 TB'], 'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'File': ['200 TB ', '100 TB', '300 TB']})

# display(df)
     Size ID     File
0  500 TB  A  200 TB 
1  200 TB  B   100 TB
2  600 TB  C   300 TB

# apply str.split and then select the value at index [0]
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(' ').str[0])

# display(df)
  Size ID File
0  500  A  200
1  200  B  100
2  600  C  300
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try `str.extract`:

```
df[['Size','File']] = df[['Size','File']].apply(lambda x: x.str.extract('^(\d+)')[0])
```

Output:

```
  Size ID File
0  500  A  200
1  200  B  100
2  600  C  300
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `str.strip`

```
df[['Size','File']] = df[['Size','File']].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(' TB'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
df['Size'] = df['Size'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('TB'))
df['File'] = df['File'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-').rstrip('TB'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also `replace`:

```
df[['Size','File']] = df[['Size','File']].replace('\s+?TB','',regex=True)
```

---

```
  Size ID File
0  500  A  200
1  200  B  100
2  600  C  300
```