# How to delete a part of a string from pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 6, 8, 9],
                'date': ['2021-07-21 04:34:02', 
                         'test_2022-17-21 04:54:22',
                        'test_2020-06-21 04:34:02',
                        '2023-12-01 11:54:52']})

df["date"].replace("test_", "")
df
```

I would like to delete 'test_' from the column date.
Maybe, you can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.strip(<unnecessary string>)` to remove the unnecessary string:

```
df.date = df.date.str.strip('test_')
```

OUTPUT:

```
   a                 date
0  2  2021-07-21 04:34:02
1  6  2022-17-21 04:54:22
2  8  2020-06-21 04:34:02
3  9  2023-12-01 11:54:52
```

Answer (score 0):

The same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682044/remove-unwanted-parts-from-strings-in-a-column). check the link. For your specific inquiry, this one line is all you want.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('test_'))
```